# Using Foundation 6.3 in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I've added the Meteor package foundation zurb:foundation-sites. This is using v.6.3 (I couldn't get the npm package to work using v6.4.1)

I've got my main.scss file importing:

```
@import '{zurb:foundation-sites}/scss/foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

My Templates:

```
Template.myReveal.onRendered(function () {
  this.myRevealInstance = new Foundation.Reveal($('#myReveal'));
});

Template.myReveal.onDestroyed(function () {
  let reveal = this.myRevealInstance;
  if (reveal) {
    reveal.destroy();
  }
});
```

My html:

```
<template name="myReveal">
<p><button class="button" data-toggle="myReveal">Click me for a modal</button></p>
<div class="reveal" id="myReveal" data-reveal data-animation-in="fade-in" data-animation-out="fade-out">
    <h1>Awesome</h1>
    <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
    <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The animation plug-in isn't working. I've tried using:

```
Template.myReveal.onRendered(function () {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

But no luck. I tried adding the zurb:motion.ui package and still no luck. How can I get the animations to work?

Comment: We can't help debug "no luck". Could you explain specifically what issues and errors you are experiencing?

Comment: The reveal modals work but with no animation. When using 'data reveal data-animation-in="fade-in", no animation of the modal is seen. It looks like this is a plug-in, but it should be initialized already.